# Automake - difficulty with installing version 'automake-1.14.1'

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, automake, raspbian

I have problem with installing automake 1.14.1 on Rapbian (2014-09-09-wheezy-raspbian) distro. I wrote `sh ./configure` and then I wrote `make` then terminal wrote me that:

```
$ make    
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && "/home/pi/LIBRARY/automake-1.14./twrap/aclocal-1.14"
Can't locate /home/pi/LIBRARY/automake-1.14.1/bin/aclocal in @INC (@INC contains:
/etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5usr
/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at 
/home/piLIBRARY/automake-1.14.1/t/wrap/aclocal-1.14 line 29.Makefile:2493: recipe 
for target 'aclocal.m4' failed make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 2
```

I don't know what does it mean. Can you help me what to do next?

Comment: Why not use a packaged version?  (ie, install from an rpm)

Comment: It looks like the configure step (if it succeeded) used a different INC for perl, or perhaps got a different perl binary.  Instead of `sh ./configure`, try just running `configure` so that the environment is the same as the shell from which you run `make`.

Comment: I tried use apt-get but this one always install old version of automake. I need automake 1.14 version would I could install bcm2835 library on raspberry Pi. I think rpm is not possible install on Raspbian distro. I tried run configure without sh command but no effect.

Comment: Dont use rpm use a .deb package

Comment: I couldn't find `automake-1.14.1.deb` on the internet. I found only `automake-1.14_1.14.1-4.debian.tar.xz` but I don't know how to install it because when I unpacked it then I obtained folder `debian` and I don't know what to do with this next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what is problem in. I use `filezilla` to transport `automake` to Raspberry Pi (running on Raspbian) in unpacked form. When I transported packed `automake.tar` through fillezila and then unpacked it on RPi and did installation of this one then I have no problem. However many thanks for all your answers and an effort to help me.

Answer (score 0):

`recipe for target 'aclocal.m4' failed make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 2`

Is saying where the failure occurred. So the failure is occurring when the make file calls `aclocal.m4`.  This is due to that `Can't locate /home/pi/LIBRARY/automake-1.14.1/bin/aclocal` so check out if `/home/pi/LIBRARY/automake-1.14.1/bin/aclocal` can be found and if not then install what is needed to resolve the error.

Comment: How to find out if aclocal can be found? In folder `/automake-1.14.1/bin/` are `aclocal.in` and `aclocal.tmp`but no `aclocal`. I think aclocal is a part of automake in old version 1.11 what is already installed. I tried run `./configure` again and now when I run `make` another error is occured `>Makefile:2463: recipe for target 'Makefile.in' failed` `make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1`

Comment: try to run a `make clean` then.

Comment: I tried run it but no effect. Last error is shown again.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully built on the same raspbian the automake-1.14.1 from ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake source tarball. The bin/aclocal script should be created at 'make' stage. Makefile.in is already included in the tarball.  There can be several reasons to such errors as you typed in your message:

- Wrong distribution source is being used: use any from ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake, http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.14.1.tar.xz
- you don't have space enough to create bin/aclocal stage at 'make' stage, check df output
- there are problems with fs consistency, read dmesg.

Comment: I used distribution of automake from source what you suggested me. No effect. I tried `df` to find out how space is free on disc (SD card on raspberry pi), I think that enough space is there. I read message invoked by `dmesg` but I don't know what to look for there. Message is quite long.

Comment: So, you don't have Makefile.in in the root folder of automake after initial unpack (last described error) or your './t/wrap/aclocal-1.14' can't find 'bin/aclocal' script (initial error in the topic description)? Which error you are dealing with?