# make on raspberry pi returns WARNING: 'automake-1.14' is missing on your system

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi

I am installing a software on a raspberry pi model B+ with the newest (29.3.2015) version of Raspbian freshly installed.

The software I am opting to install is OWFS. First I install the required software for installation

```
sudo apt-get install automake autoconf autotools-dev gcc-4.7 libtool
```

then in the unpacked software folder i run:

```
 sudo ./configure
```

and then

```
 sudo make
```

which gives this error message

```
 pi@raspberrypi ~/owfs-3.1p0 $ sudo make
 cd . && /bin/bash /home/pi/owfs-3.1p0/src/scripts/install/missing 
  automake-1.14 --foreign
/home/pi/owfs-3.1p0/src/scripts/install/missing: line 81: 
automake-1.14:     command not found
  WARNING: 'automake-1.14' is missing on your system.
     You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or
     'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
     The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:

 Makefile:494: recipe for target 'Makefile.in' failed
 make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

Comment: Seems that someone else had a very similar problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721869/automake-difficulty-with-installing-version-automake-1-14-1

Comment: In the console, what is the output of "automake --version" and "automake-1.14 --version"?

Comment: Thanks for your help Jorge Torres !
Just solved the problem an hour ago.

The problem was this:
By not selecting the locals in raspi-config correctly, Perl was no running
properly.
This prevented the header files from the installation of libusb-dev
to be placed in the right place. Thus I alway got the message after
running ./configure that USB was disabled.

So the problem was solved by making Perl work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Perl was not running:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

By setting locals properly issue was resolved.

Thanks for the help Jorge

Comment: Is it correct that Perl is required the some build processes?